# File format not recognized when trying to build makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

This is my makefile:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -c
OBJS = report.o commandLine.o configuration.o tool.o project2demo.o

project2: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o project2

report.o: report.cpp report.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) report.cpp

commandLine.o: commandLine.cpp commandLine.h tool.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) commandLine.cpp

configuration.o: configuration.cpp configuration.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) configuration.cpp

tool.o: tool.cpp tool.h
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) tool.cpp

project2demo.o: tool.h project2demo.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) project2demo.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o project2
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
file not recognized: File format not recognized collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can not figure out why this is. I looked at some similar topics, and the solutions did not work. For example, I tried deleting the object file that was not recognized (report.o) and rebuilding it. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Edit: Full error as requested:

```
report.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [project2] Error 1
```

Edit 2: I forgot to add that it works on windows. But when I connect to a linux machine using puTTy, I get this error.

Comment: Linker throws an error. Post full error message.

Comment: report.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [project2] Error 1                                                                                                         ........I forgot to add that it works on windows. But when I connect to a linux machine using puTTy, I get this error.

Comment: Do you do `make clean` when switching between Windows/Linux?

Comment: I just tried that, it got rid of the error and it seems to have compiled and linked successfully, however, when i type "project2" to execute the program, it says: -bash: project2: command not found
However, when I type "make" it says project2 is up to date. I also tried to execute it with ./a.out.

Comment: On Linux, to call program located in current directory, you have to specify the current directory explicitly - `./project2`. The current directory is not included in the default program search path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] it works on windows. But when I connect to a Linux machine using PuTTy, I get this error.

If you are using a shared file system, you need to call `make clean` when switching between Windows and Linux.

Windows and Linux use different object file formats, and as such you can not use the object files of one OS on another. When using a shared file system, the `make` will not automatically guess that the object files should be recompiled and would use the old files compiled under a different OS. That would result in the error you observed.

Comment: Thanks so much, you have been a great help! I was not aware of the make clean issue. Much appreciated!